# Passing conditional parameters to Database.SqlQuery

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I have been doing the following to pass parameters with my sql query:

```
var retval = context.MyObject.SqlQuery(sql.ToString(),
                                                 new SqlParameter("@ProductId", productId),
                                                 new SqlParameter("@CustomerId", customerId)).ToList();
```

I ran into a scenario where @CustomerId will not always be used in my sql string. Meaning I used an if statement to either add (Where p.CustomerId = @CustomerId) or keep it out.

I realized that I can't pass my parameters in directly to the SqlQuery function now. Instead I have to create an object list of parameters and then pass it in:

```
        SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter("@ProductId", productId);
        SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter("@CustomerId", customerId);
        object[] parameters = new object[] { param1, param2 };
```

How can I make it so I can use an if statement to either add the CustomerId parameter to my parameters array or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can edit your query to this

```
SELECT * FROM Product p 
WHERE 
    p.ProductId = @ProductId 
    AND (@CustomerId IS NULL OR p.CustomerId = @CustomerId)
```

Then you pass `DBNull.Value` to `@CustomerId` if it is not used

Comment: That is how I am doing all of my queries going forward, but I am bringing over a lot of functions from an older application and would prefer keeping them the same. If there is no way to do this then I will have to update all of the queries to use where clauses like you specified.

Answer (score 3):

You can try using a sql command instead as it allows using collections of parameters. But this might require you to change your code structure a bit.

```
        int a = 1;
        SqlCommand sql = new SqlCommand();
        sql.CommandText = "SELECT * FROm somwhere";

        List<SqlParameter> lstParams = new List<SqlParameter>();
        if (a == 1)
        {`enter code here`
            SqlParameter sqlParam1 = new SqlParameter();
            lstParams.Add(sqlParam1);
        }
        else if (a == 2)
        {
            SqlParameter sqlParam2 = new SqlParameter();
            lstParams.Add(sqlParam2);
        }

        sql.Parameters.AddRange(lstParams.ToArray());

        sql.BeginExecuteReader();
```